# Enable WiFi in AlertDialog crashes

Tags: java, android

If wifi or mobile data is not enabled, it should ask the user, if he clicks yes in the AlertDialog, it will go to the settings.

This is inside main, on create, when the update button clicked:

```
btnUpdate.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Log.v(TAG,"ButtonUpdate clicked");
            connectIfNecessary();
            currentDate = Calendar.getInstance();
            formatter= new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");

            new UpdateDB(MainActivity.this);
            txtLastUpdateShow.setText(formatter.format(currentDate.getTime()));
    });
```

This is connectifnecessary:

```
 public void connectIfNecessary(){
    Log.v(TAG, "main connectIfNecessary");
    if(!isConnected()){
        final Context ctx = this;
        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(ctx);
        builder.setCancelable(true);
        builder.setMessage("need internet");
        builder.setTitle("do you want to enable it now?");
        builder.setPositiveButton("yes", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                ctx.startActivity(new Intent(Settings.ACTION_WIRELESS_SETTINGS));
            }
        });
        builder.setNegativeButton("no", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                return;
            }
        });
        builder.setOnCancelListener(new DialogInterface.OnCancelListener() {
            public void onCancel(DialogInterface dialog) {
                return;
            }
        });
        builder.show();
    }

}
```

this is isConnected:

```
   public boolean isConnected(){
    Log.v(TAG, "mainisconnected");
    ConnectivityManager conectivtyManager = (ConnectivityManager)
            getApplicationContext().getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
    if (conectivtyManager.getActiveNetworkInfo() != null
            && conectivtyManager.getActiveNetworkInfo().isAvailable()
            && conectivtyManager.getActiveNetworkInfo().isConnected()) {
        Log.v(TAG, "mainisconnected true");
        return true;
    } else {
        Log.v(TAG, "mainisconnected false");

        return false;
    }
}
```

in updatedb constructor, it will call asynctask to connect websites.

When i run this, and click update button, it crashes because it goes into updatedb withpout asking me in builder. The errors:

```
  FATAL EXCEPTION: AsyncTask #1
      Process: com.cursedchico.IstanbulEventPool, PID: 13068
      java.lang.RuntimeException: An error occured while executing doInBackground()
          at android.os.AsyncTask$3.done(AsyncTask.java:300)
          at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.finishCompletion(FutureTask.java:355)
          at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.setException(FutureTask.java:222)
          at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:242)
          at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:231)
          at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1112)
          at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587)
          at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:841)
       Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
          at com.cursedchico.IstanbulEventPool.EventRetriever.doInBackground(UpdateDB.java:303)
          at com.cursedchico.IstanbulEventPool.EventRetriever.doInBackground(UpdateDB.java:109)
          at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:288)
          at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
          at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:231) 
          at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1112) 
          at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587) 
          at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:841) 
01-01 18:48:00.299 13068-13068/com.cursedchico.IstanbulEventPool E/WindowManager: android.view.WindowLeaked: Activity com.cursedchico.IstanbulEventPool.MainActivity has leaked window com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView{41e17480 V.E..... R.....I. 0,0-488,216} that was originally added here
         at android.view.ViewRootImpl.<init>(ViewRootImpl.java:388)
         at android.view.WindowManagerGlobal.addView(WindowManagerGlobal.java:248)
         at android.view.WindowManagerImpl.addView(WindowManagerImpl.java:69)
         at android.app.Dialog.show(Dialog.java:286)
         at android.support.v7.app.AlertDialog$Builder.show(AlertDialog.java:902)
         at com.cursedchico.IstanbulEventPool.MainActivity.connectIfNecessary(MainActivity.java:106)
         at com.cursedchico.IstanbulEventPool.MainActivity$6.onClick(MainActivity.java:276)
         at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4508)
         at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:18675)
         at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
         at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
         at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
         at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5584)
         at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
         at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
         at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1268)
         at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1084)
         at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
01-01 18:48:00.299 13068-13068/com.cursedchico.IstanbulEventPool E/WindowManager: android.view.WindowLeaked: Activity com.cursedchico.IstanbulEventPool.MainActivity has leaked window com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView{41e36258 V.E..... R......D 0,0-488,165} that was originally added here
         at android.view.ViewRootImpl.<init>(ViewRootImpl.java:388)
         at android.view.WindowManagerGlobal.addView(WindowManagerGlobal.java:248)
         at android.view.WindowManagerImpl.addView(WindowManagerImpl.java:69)
         at android.app.Dialog.show(Dialog.java:286)
         at android.app.ProgressDialog.show(ProgressDialog.java:117)
         at android.app.ProgressDialog.show(ProgressDialog.java:100)
         at com.cursedchico.IstanbulEventPool.EventRetriever.onPreExecute(UpdateDB.java:269)
         at android.os.AsyncTask.executeOnExecutor(AsyncTask.java:587)
         at android.os.AsyncTask.execute(AsyncTask.java:535)
         at com.cursedchico.IstanbulEventPool.UpdateDB.<init>(UpdateDB.java:56)
         at com.cursedchico.IstanbulEventPool.MainActivity$6.onClick(MainActivity.java:280)
         at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4508)
         at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:18675)
         at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
         at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
         at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
         at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5584)
         at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
         at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
         at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1268)
         at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1084)
         at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

MainActivity.java:106) is builder.show()
MainActivity.java:276) connectIfNecessary();

I am getting errors for hours, at first about appcompat, then manifest then layout now this.

I use real tablet device.

Comment: Are you executing any AsyncTask ?

Comment: Show `EventRetriever ` class code

Comment: i want it not to run updatedb. inside update db, there is yes asynctask. With wifi on, it works good. When i disable wifi and run the app, it again runs it instead of asking me with builder to enable wifi. Do you understand? I dont want my app to run asynctask before enabling wifi.

Comment: Please check the below portion of log

    Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException at  
    com.cursedchico.IstanbulEventPool.EventRetriever.doInBackground(UpdateDB.java:303)

Its an `NPE`. Check the code in `UpdateDB.java` `doInBackground()` method of `Asynctask` line number `303`. There is an uninitialized value, Fix it.

Comment: hey.there is no internet so it can not connect websites and give those errors. I need to stop going there before asking me inside alerbuilder to enable wifi

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When device is not connected , following would be execution flow

- Get inside connectIfNecessary()
- Create Alert to ask user to enable internet. Please note that only Alter object is created at this moment, it will be displayed on screen only after stack of main thread unwinds.
- Return from connectIfNecessary() create instance of updateDB(). Inside this application is crashing

Few simple changes would fix your code.

- add *isConnected()* if check before creating instance of updateDB(). This will cover the CONNECTED case
- if the device is NOT CONNECTED, user will shown the alter and take to settings screen. If user enables WIFI from settings and comes back, onResume() of your activity will be called. Check connectivity and add updateDB() here.

Comment: but for that, i need a while to check if is connected=true or am i wrong?

Comment: you don't need a while loop (I'm not talking about polling), just a simple if check will do.

Comment: for example we did check and come to resume but still not enabled and if it goes further, it will go to code that needs internet. How can we fix this or am i thinking wrong? sorry for going on.

Comment: Valid point..even in resume method you will have put connected==true check and in else case display the alert to enable internet. Hope this answers your question.

Comment: so we need while? because if i put only a if, it will go inside onclick method and go from that method without doing anything.